# Сформированный пакет клиент не может отправить серверу по tcp

Tags: c++, qt

Всем привет.
Столкнулся с проблемой отправки сформированного пакета от клиента серверу.
Нашел старый вопрос где комментатор расписал по сути то что я и делаю.
[Сообщение от клиента серверу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1058127/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-tcp-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)

У клиента я формирую пакет такого вида ""header""message.size""message""
Соединение установлено, но клиент ничего не отправляет.
Ниже 2 метода, один проверка и отправка а второй(из буфера) отдает для отправки сам пакет

```
void MyClient::sendToServer()
{
    if(m_pBuffNetworkWrite->getSize() > 32)
    {
    uint8_t size = m_pBuffNetworkWrite->getSize();

    auto buffToServer = m_pBuffNetworkWrite->popUp(size);

    auto countSendData = m_pSocket->write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(buffToServer));

    if (countSendData > 0)
    {
        qDebug() << "data sent to server";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "data not sent to server";
    }
}
```

Этот метод отдает данные которые были уже раньше записаны и размер самого пакета.

```
uint8_t* BuffNetworkWrite::popUp(int size)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&m_mutex);

    if (m_iSize < size)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }

    auto* pTmp = new uint8_t(size);

    memset(pTmp, 0, size);
    memcpy(pTmp, m_pData, size);

    memcpy(m_pData, m_pData + size, m_iSize - size);
    m_iSize = size;

    return pTmp;
}
```

Буду признателен за советы или указание где стоит искать проблему.

Добавляю метод которым я формирую пакет

```
uint8_t *PackNetwork::toByte(uint32_t &size)
{
    uint8_t *dataBuffer = new uint8_t[m_packHeader.size]; // буфер размером заголовок + размер сообщения + сообщение
    memcpy(dataBuffer, &m_packHeader, sizeof(packHeader));
    uint8_t *byteData = nullptr;

    uint32_t offset = sizeof(packHeader);

    for (auto &item : m_dataList)
    {
        uint32_t sizeData = 0;

        byteData = item->toByte(sizeData); // после метода sizeData имеет размер сообщения, byteData это сообщение
        memcpy(dataBuffer + offset, byteData, sizeData);

        offset += sizeData;
    }

    size = m_packHeader.size;

    return dataBuffer;
}
```

Аргумент size при входе в метод 0 а после уже меняется.
Если я в методе заменю возвращение пакета то что мне надо дял сервера просто на строку из byteData то сервер реагирует на примем. И само собою у клиенат я вижу сообщение data sent to server

Comment: Я все же думаю, что нужен [минимально воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
Как Вы убедились, что проблема на стороне клиента? Увидели сообщение "data not sent to server"?

Comment: Я к топику добавил метод который отвечает за формирование пакета с нужной инфой для сервера. В данном методе я и пробовал менять параметры возврата пакета на простое сообщение.

Comment: Я считаю, еще и серверная часть не лишней будет.

Comment: Уже не знаю как добавить уже ответом код с серверной части.void MyServer::incomingConnection(qintptr socketDescriptor)
{
    // New connection
    Client *client = new Client(m_pBuffNetworkRead, m_pBuffNetworkWrite,this);
    if (!client->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor))
    {
        client->deleteLater();
        return;
    }

Comment: По сути при новом соединении получаю дескриптор и передаю классу Клиент, а там через коннект connect(m_pServerSocket, &QTcpSocket::readyRead, this, &Client::slotReadyRead);

Comment: Можете что-то посоветовать?

Comment: Отправьте что-нибудь простое и маленькое и без мьютекса. Клиент-сервер у Вас работают? У Вас при каких-то условиях буфер отправки - nullptr. Я же не могу это воспроизвести у себя.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142047/discussion-between-alexey-ananyev-and-eugesh).

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. Как оказалось метод write с одним аргументом это для простых сообщений, на подобии слова. А с двумя аргументами это уже для пакетов. Я попробовал второй вариант и сервер принял пакет.